# Tabular: How to reset the {cols} specification

Tags: tables, columns

```
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{r@{$\pm$}l}
      % two columns, a \pm between each two
      4 & 5 \\
      2 & 3 \\
      % ... after n row, I want to have two regular columns WITHOUT \pm
      Text & Other text \\ %no need to \pm here
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{itemize}
```

See the above.
Basically, I want to reset the specification of `r$\pm$l` after a certain number of row (or have it be applied to those rows only).
Any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: `{r$\pm$l}` is a syntax error so it is hard to know what to suggest, please always post _complete_ documents not fragments so that you can test before posting. Do you mean `r@{$\pm$}l` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, yes, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a separator of

```
@{\mysep}
```

with

```
\gdef\mysep{$\pm$}
```

before the table and

```
\gdef\mysep{\phantom{$\pm$}}
```

at the point you want the change.

(untested as no test document provided)